# What's the difference between 'family shame' or 'family's shame'?

Tags: apostrophe

Apostrophe indicates a possession, so my question is do I use it in the phrase: *Family('s) shame*?

Basically, I don't think my family possesses me that's why I am a little bit confused.
The full phrase is:

> "I am my family('s) shame"

Comment: But they do (potentially) 'possess' / 'own' the shame. Even when 'shame' is used metaphorically (to some degree), as here,  I'd say the apostrophe is better. And the 'possesses' 'rule' is not so simple. "The disease's consequences can be severe" is fine, though the concept of possession would have to be stretched to cover such a case.

Comment: Agree. But, let's put it this way, can I say "Family Shame"?

Comment: 'I am my family shame' is totally unidiomatic.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help :)
Oh, could you explain the "disease's" example for me, please?

Comment: ... disease's consequences ... is simply another way of saying ... consequences of the disease ... .

Comment: @ MetaEd [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shame) n4: a person or thing that causes [shame]. Compare 'The pride of ...'.

Comment: I thought there was some hidden meaning

Comment: I'm just trying to say that I am the shame of my family. Not just have shamed my family like a one time thing. Constant shame

Comment: Probably the closest one is: My family is ashamed of me

Comment: Or "I *bring shame to* (or on) my family".

Comment: I need this specific phrase, so I decided to ask. Thank you, though :)

Comment: **The shame of my family** is far more idiomatic.

Comment: Which all avoids the real question which is - what exactly did you do?

Comment: I am so happy to see that one person just says it: I am my family shame=unidiomatic. I agree  completely, though family shame is a complex subject.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  Wow - so sad, dramatic, and confusing -- too personal.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am my family's shame."

This sentence is fine.

I hope you feel better after communicating your view to the desired party.

Answer (score 0):

As noted already by others, the following is correct:

> "I am my family's shame".

This doesn't mean that your family owns *you*. It means that your family owns the *shame* that it associates with with you. You could also say, "I am the shame of my family."

I know this is outside the scope of your question, but I hope you're talking about a novel you're writing, not a real-life situation. If the latter, I offer a quote you may find of value (adapted from the many words of wisdom of the German philosopher Friedrich Nietzsche):

> *What is the seal of one's liberation?*  Not to be ashamed in front of
>   one's self .. or anyone else, for that matter.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing something. It isn't based on my personal experience. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Family's shame" means "the shame of my family", as covered in [Richard Kayser's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/349905/91730).

"Family shame" would be using "family" as an adjective to describe "shame". For example:

> I'm so embarrassed by my parents, I try to avoid letting friends meet them; I suffer from *family shame*.